# Guidelines on rewriting vs deleting?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

What is the basic rule for rewriting a question, as opposed to deleting it and asking a different question?

Comment: I've removed your specific example because we need to strive for general answers and question here on meta instead of discussing personal cases.

Comment: Related: [Rewrite or delete?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1188/rewrite-or-delete) (This is about answers)

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, it's best to stick to rewriting. By deleting the older version and posting a new version, you're circumventing the voting system and closure. That's frowned upon.

There are a few situations where posting a new question might be appropriate:

1. **Your existing question has a score of -5 or below and you believe your edit will fix the question.**

   Questions which have a score of -5 or lower will not be displayed on the front page. In the case of a major improvement to the question, it might be worth reposting the improved version of the question so it can get reevaluated by the community.
2. **There are already answers to your question and they would be invalidated by the edit.**

   If there already are answers to your question and you make a change that completely changes the scope of the question, it might be better off leaving your question closed and posting a new one.